# <stdarg.h> Mixed input types for a function that uses va_list

Tags: c, function, casting

I want to write a function that allocates a dynamic array of float values using function from '''stdarg.h'''. The problem is that input of function contains mixed float/int values and after using '''va_arg(va,double)''', int values are truncated to 0.
How to write such a function that for different input types, store their values after type casting, without manually casting each func. input argument?

Some code that I wrote :

```
float *allocVec(int n,...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, n);
    printf("sizeof %ld\n",sizeof(va));
    float *vector;

    vector = (float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float));

    //this function checks if memory were allocated succesfully
    CheckAlloc(vector);
    for(int i = 0 ;i < n ; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = (float) va_arg(va,double);
        printf("%f \n",vector[i]);
    }
    va_end(va);
    return vector;
}

int main()
{
    allocVec(3,7.2,-1,0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `allocVec` needs to know the type of each variable. Either it needs to be told explicitly or by prior agreement when defining the API. There is no way around that. That's why functions like `printf` have the first parameter as a format string which describes all the variable types that follow.

Comment: C has no type information at its values. A called function can not know the types of variadic arguments if not told.

Comment: The part of your question that validates your desire to use a `variadic` argument list: _that for different input types_, does not mesh with the other criteria you describe: _that input of function contains mixed float/int values_.  i.e. I see no compelling reason to use `variadic` when the only thing that changes between calls to the allocVec, is the value of each argument, not the type.  As long as every call will have the same number of input args, and the type of each input arg is the same, `variadic` is not needed.